# Добавление товара в корзину на js. в консоль выводит undefined.Помогите разобраться

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```js
//этот код менять нельзя
function Cart () {

}
Cart.prototype.add = function (item) {
    if (!this.goods) {
        this.goods = [];
    }
    this.goods.push(item); //добавляет товар в корзину
};


//редактируемый код
function UserCart () {

}


function Item (idNum, item, sum) {
   this.idNum = idNum;
   this.item = item;
   this.sum = sum;
}

UserCart.prototype = Object.create(Cart.prototype);


const cart = new UserCart();
const item = new Item("1", 'Сhair', "20$");

cart.add();
console.log(cart.goods);
```

Comment: добавьте `return item`,  будет возвращать что-то

Comment: а что именно ты ожидал увидеть в логе?

Comment: _товар должен добавляться в корзину с помощью функции add_ - так а в логе ты что хотел увидеть-то? Почему ты думаешь, что товар не добавился?

Comment: `cart.add(item); console.log(cart.goods);`- так вы увидите, что сработало

Comment: https://eval.in/899791

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте вывод в консоль в методе Cart.prototype.add, например так:

```
Cart.prototype.add = function (item) {
    if (!this.goods) {
        this.goods = [];
    }
    this.goods.push(item); //добавляет товар в корзину
    console.log('В корзине %s товаров', this.goods.length)
};
```

И посмотрите вывод

Comment: Не совсем понял вопрос, уточните пожалуйста.

Comment: Евгения, читать код в таком формате очень сложно. Выложите пожалуйста ваш код на jsfiddle.net дайте сюда ссылку

Answer (score 0):

> cart.add(item);

```
cart.add(item);
```

Код полностью:

```js
//этот код менять нельзя
function Cart () {

}
Cart.prototype.add = function (item) {
    if (!this.goods) {
        this.goods = [];
    }
    this.goods.push(item); //добавляет товар в корзину
};


//редактируемый код
function UserCart () {

}


function Item (idNum, item, sum) {
   this.idNum = idNum;
   this.item = item;
   this.sum = sum;
}

UserCart.prototype = Object.create(Cart.prototype);


const cart = new UserCart();
const item = new Item("1", 'Сhair', "20$");

cart.add(item);
console.log(cart.goods);
```